# Accessing XML file in a NuGet package

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget-package, xml-documentation

I have an API in ASP Dotnet Core.

I'm using Swashbuckle to generate Swagger documentation for my API. It uses the XML documentation file to populate the descriptions of routes and objects, which works fine for the models that are included in the project. However most of the models this API uses are included in a dependent project (the Models project).

The Models project generates its XML documentation and it is packaged into the NuGet package, so it should be available. Is there a way I can read this XML file out of the NuGet package at runtime, so that Swashbuckle can use it?